# Options binomial

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, finance

here is my question:

You have a binomial process where   \begin{equation} 
 Z_j 
\end{equation}

is a random variable taking the value of one with probability p and the value of minus one otherwise.

We have a stock price  the log of which follows the following process:
\begin{equation} 
 logS_t=logS_0+\mu(T)+\sigma\sqrt(T/N)\ \sum_{j=1}^{N} Z_j 
\end{equation}

We want to find out what happens as N goes to infinity

The risk-neutral probability for the up move is given by the following equation:

\begin{equation}
  q=\frac{e^{(r-\mu)dt}-e^{-\sigma\sqrt{dt}}}{e^{\sigma\sqrt{dt}}-e^{-\sigma\sqrt{dt}}}
\end{equation}

which after expansion equals:

\begin{equation} 
 q= 1/2(1-\sqrt{dt}(\frac{\mu+0.5\sigma^2-r}{\sigma})) 
\end{equation}

So now \begin{equation} 
 Z_j 
\end{equation}

instead of zero and 1 has approximately:

\begin{equation} 
 mean= \sqrt{dt}(\frac{r-\mu-0.5\sigma^2}{\sigma})
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation} 
 variance= 1-dt(\frac{r-\mu-0.5\sigma^2}{\sigma})^2
\end{equation}

Now what I don't understand is how from this follows that the mean of logSt is:

\begin{equation} 
 logS_0+(r-0.5\sigma^2)T
\end{equation}

and the variance of logSt is:

\begin{equation} 
 \sigma^2T
\end{equation}

Comment: I assume $r$ is the risk-free rate and $\mu,\sigma$ are parameters determined by the stock.  Is $T = t$ and $T/N = dt$?  (e.g. as a discretization?)

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: I am assuming is that you substitute the new mean and variance in the logS process instead of Z but I am not 100% sure